# Interfaces x any

Tags: typescript, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any drawbacks from using 'any' instead of an interface in cases like this ?

First with an interface for Item :

```
imports ...
export interface Item { name: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  my template
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
  items: Observable<Item[]>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('items');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Without an interface, with 'any'

```
imports...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
     my template
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  items: Observable<Any[]>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<any>('items');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `any` in this situation is a bad practice. Basically, you're throwing away one of the most important parts of TypeScript ([which is type system](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html)), and its benefits (compile time type checking). Do **not** do it unless it's a necessity.

I recommend to use `any` in two situations only:

- when you are truly dealing with object of unpredictable types. Even then you may want to first declare an `interface` type to declare a contract (which in runtime may or may not be fulfilled).
- when you use "[ambient declarations](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/intro.html)" for JavaScript libraries that do not have corresponding `@types/*` npm modules. This is really a last resort. Good news, ambient declarations are faced less and less frequently nowadays.

Comment: Is it possible to use class instead of interface?